# node-opencv cant access any cameras

Tags: node.js, opencv, raspberry-pi

Trying to opencv working on my raspberry pi using node.js but Im having lots of errors.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/node $ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Camera Board OV5647 (CSI):
    /dev/video2

HD USB Camera (usb-3f980000.usb-1.2):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

running this code
    var cv = require('opencv');

```
try {
  var camera = new cv.VideoCapture(2);
  var window = new cv.NamedWindow('Video', 0)
  while(true)
  camera.read(err,im);
  window.show(im);
} catch (e){
  console.log("Couldn't start camera:", e)
}
```

using /dev/video0

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/node $ node camera
Couldn't start camera: [ReferenceError: err is not defined]
```

using /dev/video1

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/node $ node camera
libv4l2: error set_fmt gave us a different result then try_fmt!
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable convert to requested pixfmt
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl VIDIOCSPICT
Couldn't start camera: [Error: Camera could not be opened]
```

using /dev/video0

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/node $ node camera
/dev/video2 does not support memory mapping
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
Unable to stop the stream.: Bad file descriptor
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
Couldn't start camera: [ReferenceError: err is not defined]
```

usb cam has the following formats

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/node $ v4l2-ctl --list-formats -d /dev/video0
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
Index       : 0
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
Name        : MJPEG

Index       : 1
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)

pi@raspberrypi:~/node $ v4l2-ctl --list-formats -d /dev/video1
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
Index       : 0
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'H264' (compressed)
Name        : H.264
```

the camera is a ELP 720p Full Hd H.264 USB Camera Module though I doubt anyone else has one